# Combinations of 4 numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A four-digit house number contains no zeros.  The number has exactly three distinct digits.  How many house numbers are possible?

I have been having issues trying to handle the fact the 2 numbers are same. 
What I have tried is:

9C3 * 3C1 * 4P4 = 6048

Is this the correct way?  Or am I missing something here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 9C3 chooses the digits and 3C1 chooses which digit will be repeated, which is fine.  The 4P4 is supposed to put the digits in order, but you can swap the two matching ones to no effect.  There are only $\frac{4P4}{2!}=\frac {24}2=12$ ways to order four digits including one pair, so you are overcounting by a factor $2$.  Another way to get there is you choose two slots of the four for the matching digits, $4C2=6$ then choose the order for the remaining two, $2P2=2$, giving a product of $12$

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you, I figured I was missing something, and that makes complete sense!